# Does the @properties decorator cache results?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

My IDE has *"corrected"* my code to convert a function (and other code) to a property.  I am worried that it might be inefficient.

```
@property
def output_all_children(self):
    lh = ListHolder()
    traverse_directories(self.start_directory, lh)
    return lh.internal_list
```

this does some heavy I/O lifting and takes some time.  I am wondering now if this is incorrect due to efficiency reasons.  I am wondering if the results aren't cached like I hoping would happen.

If this property is accessed several times is it going to rebuild and return the lh.internal_list every time?
I would correct this by having a class level variable and updating it when self.start_directory is changed.

I have looked at this:
[How to create decorator for lazy initialization of a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237678/how-to-create-decorator-for-lazy-initialization-of-a-property) and it refers to a read-only property while mine would be a updated property

Please no comments on trusting IDEs blindly.  I know and that thinking prompted this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a property merely translates attribute access into a function call. No automatic caching takes place.

In other words, the syntax `instance.output_all_children` is translated into `instance.output_all_children()` for you.

You can easily add some caching to a property method, or you can reuse the code you link to in your question; merely replace the `__set__` method to handle attribute assignment, if you so desire.

Adding some caching:

```
_output_all_children = None

@property
def output_all_children(self):
    if self._output_all_children is None:
        lh = ListHolder()
        traverse_directories(self.start_directory, lh)
        self._output_all_children = lh.internal_list
    return self._output_all_children
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the property will be called each time. This isn't a good use of a property; callers will expect it to take not much longer than an attribute access.

There's a lovely decorator in Pyramid called `reify` that calls the function the first time, then sets the value as a same-named attribute on the object so that the previously-calculated value is used the next time.

If you don't want to use Pyramid just for the one decorator, you can use this version I wrote (it works like Pyramid's but I wrote it independently):

```
import functools

def reify(func):

    class Descriptor(object):
        def __get__(self, inst, type=None):
            val = func(inst)
            setattr(inst, func.__name__, val)
            return val

    return functools.wraps(func)(Descriptor())
```

To make it work nicely with your use case, just `del` the attribute off the instance when you need it to be recalculated:

```
@reify
def all_children(self):
    lh = ListHolder()
    traverse_directories(self.start_directory, lh)
    return lh.internal_list

# for internal use only, call when a cached all_children may no longer be valid
def _invalidate_all_children(self):
    try:
        del self.all_children
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```