# Making a LazilyEvaluatedConstantProperty class in Python

Tags: python, attributes, properties

There's a little thing I want to do in Python, similar to the built-in `property`, that I'm not sure how to do.

I call this class `LazilyEvaluatedConstantProperty`. It is intended for properties that should be calculated only once and do not change, but they should be created lazily rather than on object creation, for performance.

Here's the usage:

```
class MyObject(object):

    # ... Regular definitions here

    def _get_personality(self):
        # Time consuming process that creates a personality for this object.
        print('Calculating personality...')
        time.sleep(5)
        return 'Nice person'

    personality = LazilyEvaluatedConstantProperty(_get_personality)
```

You can see that the usage is similar to `property`, except there's only a getter, and no setter or deleter.

The intention is that on the first access to `my_object.personality`, the `_get_personality` method will be called, and then the result will be cached and `_get_personality` will never be called again for this object.

What is my problem with implementing this? I want to do something a bit tricky to improve performance: I want that after the first access and `_get_personality` call, `personality` will become a data attribute of the object, so lookup will be faster on subsequent calls. But I don't know how it's possible since I don't have a reference to the object.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Oh, it seems that descriptors do have access to the object on which they were defined-- I shouldn't have skimmed the tutorial. I'll be working on it, and I'll update with an answer.

Comment: Check out this thread, if you haven't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012421/python-lazy-property-decorator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented it:

```
class CachedProperty(object):
    '''
    A property that is calculated (a) lazily and (b) only once for an object.

    Usage:

        class MyObject(object):

            # ... Regular definitions here

            def _get_personality(self):
                print('Calculating personality...')
                time.sleep(5) # Time consuming process that creates personality
                return 'Nice person'

            personality = CachedProperty(_get_personality)

    '''
    def __init__(self, getter, name=None):
        '''
        Construct the cached property.

        You may optionally pass in the name that this property has in the
        class; This will save a bit of processing later.
        '''
        self.getter = getter
        self.our_name = name


    def __get__(self, obj, our_type=None):

        if obj is None:
            # We're being accessed from the class itself, not from an object
            return self

        value = self.getter(obj)

        if not self.our_name:
            if not our_type:
                our_type = type(obj)
            (self.our_name,) = (key for (key, value) in 
                                vars(our_type).iteritems()
                                if value is self)

        setattr(obj, self.our_name, value)

        return value
```

For the future, the maintained implementation could probably be found here:

https://github.com/cool-RR/GarlicSim/blob/master/garlicsim/garlicsim/general_misc/caching/cached_property.py