# Expensive precalculated data only relevant to one function

Tags: python

I find myself writing code like this relatively often:

```
_munge_text_re = re.compile("... complicated regex ...")
def munge_text(text):
    match = _munge_text_re.match(text)
    ... do stuff with match ...
```

Only `munge_text` uses `_munge_text_re`, so it would be better to make it local to the function somehow, but if I move the `re.compile` line inside the `def` then it will be evaluated every time the function is called, defeating the purpose of compiling the regular expression.

Is there a way to make `_munge_text_re` local to `munge_text` while still evaluating its initializer only once?  The single evaluation needn't happen at module load time; on the first invocation of `munge_text` would be good enough.

The example uses a regex, and the majority of the time I need this it's for a regex, but it could be any piece of data that's expensive to instantiate (so you don't wanna do it every time the function is called) and fixed for the lifetime of the program.  `ConfigParser` instances also come to mind.

Extra credit: For reasons too tedious to get into here, my current project requires extreme backward compatibility, so a solution *that works in Python 2.0* would be better than one that doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Now that it has state, just make a class for it:

```
class TextMunger(object):

    def __init__(self, regex):
        self._pattern = regex
        self._munge_text_re = None

    def __call__(self, text):
        if self._munge_text_re is None:
            self._munge_text_re = re.compile(self._pattern)

        match = self._munge_text_re.match(text)
        # ... do stuff with match ...

munge_text = TextMunger("... complicated regex ...")

# The rest of your code stays the same
```

In case you didn't know, the `__call__` method on a class means that objects can be called as though they were functions, so you can continue to use `munge_text(text)` just as you did before.

(This kind of problem is actually what led to my question about a [lazy property decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012421/python-lazy-property-decorator) in Python, which might also interest you; I wouldn't bother with that unless you find yourself repeating this pattern a lot though.)

Comment: +1, nice approach — but how do you do this so the docstring and such "look right" to introspection (in ipython/code completers/etc)?

Comment: @Dougal - good question. Usually I'm only interested in what Sphinx picks up, so it's enough to document the class as you would for any other class. You could try assigning to `self.__doc__`, but this won't fool eg. `help(munge_text)`. Maybe it **will** work  for the other tools you use regardless. If not, maybe post it as another question.

Answer (score 1):

```
_munge_text_re = None
def munge_text(text):
    global _munge_text_re
    _munge_text_re = _munge_text_re or re.compile("... complicated regex ...")
    match = _munge_text_re.match(text)
    ... do stuff with match ...
```

Comment: That ... doesn't actually get rid of the global variable ...

Comment: No, but it gets rid of the expensive initialization

Comment: @Malvolio OP wanted to use locals though.

Comment: The other solution is no better: instead of having a module-level variable that's only used to cache the RE, there's a module-level class that's only used to cache the RE.  Python isn't the best language for flexible scoping.

Comment: I wondered if you could get rid of both globals and classes by using some kind of closure, but as far as I can see you'd still end up with a second global function.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach -- one I mention only for information, and not because I'd use it in production, so I'll community-wiki this -- would be to store the state in the function itself.  You could use `hasattr`, or catch an `AttributeError`:

```
def munge1(x):
    if not hasattr(munge1, 'val'):
        print 'expensive calculation'
        munge1.val = 10
    return x + munge1.val

def munge2(x):
    try:
        munge2.val
    except AttributeError:
        print 'expensive calculation'
        munge2.val = 10
    return x + munge2.val
```

after which

```
>>> munge1(3)
expensive calculation
13
>>> munge1(3)
13
>>> munge2(4)
expensive calculation
14
>>> munge2(4)
14
```

but to be honest, I usually switch to a class at this point.

Comment: N.B. this does *not* work with Python 2.0.

Comment: @Zack: it works with recent Pythons, even in the 2.x line.  Or do you mean 2.0 literally, i.e. the one which came out over a decade ago?

Comment: Yes, I literally mean 2.0.  Backward compatibility all the way to 2.0 is a requirement for this particular project.  You would probably be happier not knowing the rationale.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following, I suppose:

```
def munge_text(text):
    global munge_text
    _munge_text_re = re.compile("... complicated regex ...")
    def t(text):
       match = _munge_text_re.match(text)
       ... do stuff with match ...
    munge_text = t
    return t(text)
```