# Python: How to condition the execution of a part of a function on the return values

Tags: python, function

I would like to implement a function `f` which returns two values `x` and `y` given an input `w`. This function first computes the value of `x` using `w` and then `y` using the computed valued of `x`. However, since the computation of `y` is expensive, I want the function to compute its value only when I need the result from the function.

That is, the following call to `f` will not execute the part of the function which computes `y` ...

```
x, _ = f(w)
```

... and the following call will execute it ...

```
x, y = f(w)
```

Is it possible to define the function in this way? Of course, a straightforward alternative is to pass an extra Boolean variable into `f` which determines whether `y` is to be computed or not but I'm wondering if there are other ways to do this. Thanks!

Comment: As Marijn says, this isn't possible.  Also, _ is actually a variable here: trying doing `print _` after that statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the perfect case for a generator, with which you can delay the execution till you want it.

```
def defer_huge_operation(w):
    ...
    yield x
    ...
    ...
    ...
    yield y

op = defer_huge_operation(w)
x = next(op)
...
...
y = next(op)
```

When you do `next(op)`, it will yield the value of `x` and the control will be returned to the main program and when you do `next(op)` again, the execution will be resumed from the place you left off and the huge operation will be performed to give you `y`.

**Note:** Once you consumed the generator completely, further `next` calls to the generator will raise `StopIteration` exception. Even if you want to do the same operation again, you need to create a new generator object like this

```
op = defer_huge_operation(w)
```

If you want to get all the values yielded by the generator, just iterate it with `list` or `tuple` function, like this

```
returned_values_list = list(defer_huge_operation(w))
```

Comment: I normally think of generators as being for generating a sequence of data of the same type, rather than two parts of a related calculation.  This requires the caller to know how many values to expect.  Whilst it works, I'm not sure I'd consider it idiomatic.

Comment: I think the egenerator idea is pretty nice, but why not just do 2 functions - you have the value needed to continue so the heavy function can be called conditionally.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful! I didn't know about yield before. So I'm assuming it should be ok for me to repeatedly do a `op = defer_huge_operation(w)` followed by just a single `x = next(op)` as long as I only need `x`, and then finally add a `y = next(op)` after the `x = next(op)` when I do actually need the `y`.

Comment: @user1953384 Yup, that should be perfectly fine :)

Comment: @user1953384 while it would work, I would say this is bad practice: its not readable and bug prone  (what if you comment out the first `next(op)` later?).  I would suggest you use two different functions, one for `x` and another for `y` or pass a boolean flag, or use the lazy props result I suggested. Those are much better in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to return an object with [lazy properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3013910/519995) from the function, so the results will evaluate only when you read them the first time.

ie.

```
result = f(w)
x = result.x  # only x is calculated now
y = result.y  # y is calculated only here
y2 = result.y  # y isn't calculated a second time
```