# What's the closest implementation of scala's '@transient lazy val' in Python?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, lazy-evaluation

According to this post:

[Python memoising/deferred lookup property decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012421/python-memoising-deferred-lookup-property-decorator)

A mnemonic decorator can be used to declare a lazy property in a class. There is even an 'official' package that can be used out of the box:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lazy

however, both of these implementation has a severe problem: any memorized values will be attempted to be pickled by python. If these values are unpicklable it will cause the program to break down.

My question is: is there an easy way to implement scala's "@transient lazy val" declaration without too much tinkering? This declaration should remember the property in case of multiple invocation, and drop it once the class/object is serialized.

Answer (score 1):

Unaware of scala implementation details, but the easiest solution comes to my mind, if you're satisfied with other aspects of the 'lazy property' library you've found, would be implementing `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` object methods, as described in [Pickling and unpickling normal class instances](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-normal-class-instances)

These methods are called by pickle/unpickle handler during object instance (de)serialization.

This way you can have fine-grained control of how/which attributes of your object serialized. 
You should read corresponding documentation on another two pickle-related methods as well (take care of `__getinitargs__` specifically).
Python deserialized objects initialization differes from common `__new__` & `__init__` sequence

Comment: I thought of it, but I cannot find any __getstate__ implementation in the superclass as a point of reference, plus, the point of decorator is simplicity, if the decorator cannot affect pickling composition on its own, then I don't think its a very convenient decorator.

Comment: as Python pickle documentation states:
`If there is no __getstate__() method, the instance’s __dict__ is pickled`. So you can simply pickle/unpickle superclass `__dict__` yourself.
Ability to handle such properties only with decorators... Hmm, I'm not sure of it